# Dual Boot Question

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-vista, multi-boot

How do I add a linux partition to the Vista/7 bootloader?

Here's a *teensy weeensy complication*: The target partition has no bootloader, such as grub or lilo installed and I can't install them. Also, the said machine has no internet connection.

EDIT:

I partitioned instead of using a VM because the VM won't recognize 64 bit CPU as x64. Again, no network involved here, so a different VM is not an option.

Comment: Windows can't read Linux filesystems (at least not by default), so the only thing you can verify in Windows would be the partitions using either fdisk at the command line, or Computer Management under Administrative Tools in the Control Panel.  This won't tell you what's on the partition, though.

Comment: It was unpartitioned before, so can I assume the the partition is Linux if it is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Zurahn mentioned, [ultimatebootcd](http://ultimatebootcd.com/) is a really nice free utility. Not to get off-topic but have you considered using VirtualBox or VMWorkstation to avoid dual-booting/partitioning headaches? You didn't specify exactly *why* you had to dual boot. These days I virtualize when I can to avoid dual/triple booting intricacies. You can reclaim the disk space you partitioned for Linux and all you'll *really* end up using is more CPU/RAM, but these days those aren't too expensive. Just my two cents.

Comment: see why I can't dual boot in edit.

Comment: Ah... okay. Wasn't sure if there was a reason for avoiding a VM. Give the UltimateBootCD a try at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting it on the initial installation with the CD, have you tried installing it afterward once the OS itself is installed?

```
grub-install
```

is the command used for that, and if it's not available,

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

should get you started.

Comment: I can't get into  Linux once it's installed - the bootloader won't install. The question becomes: how to install grub on Ubuntu through windows vista/7

Comment: A tool I use called Ultimate Boot CD (ultimatebootcd.com) includes various startup tools including a bootloader.  You can load the bootloader off the CD at runtime to get in and go from there.

Comment: The easiest way is to boot into Ubuntu and install it from there.  You can use SmartBootManager (IIRC it's under Filesystem Tools) to choose which partition to boot from.

Comment: From which menu?

Comment: Filesystem Tools->Boot Managers->Smart BootManager

Comment: Question changed - please modify your answer if you want to.